# When does equality hold in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Give example of two vectors $x$ and $y$ such that $$||x+y||_2^2 = ||x||_2^2+||y||_2^2$$

and
$$<x,y>\neq0$$

I can't seem to find any two vectors $x$ and $y$ that satisfied both conditions at the same time.

Comment: $0=\|x+y\|^2-\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2=(x+y,x+y)-\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2$$=(x,y)+(y,x)=2Re(x,y)$. This tells you what to aim for.

Comment: Actually no. $(3,4) \cdot (4,-3) = 12-12 = 0$, which does not meet the conditions.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: No. Real inner product spaces does not satisfy these conditions simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

In $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{C}$-space, with $(z,w)=z\overline{w}$

> $$|1+i|^2=2=1+1=|1|^2+|i|^2$$
>  and $$(1,i)=1\overline{i}=-i\neq0$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x\perp y$, then $\|x+y\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2$.

E.g., for  $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$,

$\|x+y\|^2=(x+y)^T(x+y)=x^Tx+2x^Ty+y^y=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2*x^Ty$

if the dot product between the two is zero (i.e. $<x,y>=x^Ty=0$), then you have: $\|x+y\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2$

Comment: But the second condition which is the dot product between 2vectors can't be zero.